Why inf of average integral greater than
While going through some reading, I encounter difficulty on why this is precisely true though ( technical details). Can someone help me, hypothesis may be more here.
$f_k -1 \to 0$ in $W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)$.
On the one hand, we have
$$
   \|\nabla f_{k}\|_{L^{p}(\mathbb{R}^{n})} \xrightarrow{k \to \infty} 0.
$$
Why we can assume the existence of $R_k \in (0,1)$, for $k \in \mathbb{N}$, and $\lim_{k \to \infty} R_k = 0$, such that
$$
 \inf_{r > R_k, x \in B_1} \frac{1}{|B_{r}(x)|}\int\limits_{B_{r}(x)} f_k \geq \frac{9}{10}.
$$?
